# mysql - user account and userprofile design

Tags: mysql

[image: schema]I currently have a database design for a school. I have 5 user types, student, faculty, admin, registrar, and accounting. My primary design was to add a password to each table, and use their user id as the username, then i'd use a union query on the php page. i know it is wrong, so i decided to return on using a usertable. but i am strugling to think about how would i connect the 5 profiles (5 different tables) to a single user table for login. This might seem as an easy question for some, so pardon me. 
I am including the link of my sql table for reference to what i did, and yes. i know there are a lot of flaws in it. any help would be greatly appreciated.
Link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dBrCUz-f-mV95x2sKY2OSl0Q94Mtz85f

Comment: why you not using view for mysql?

Comment: Please include all **relevant** information in your question, not in external links.

Comment: added a schema of the database.